# Cordova Plugin not loading com.google.zxing.client.j2se

Tags: java, cordova, cordova-plugins

I'm working on a Cordova Plugin and want to add the functionality of printing QR codes. In order to do that I decided to use the ZXing library.

I'm registering the dependencies of the library in the `plugin.xml` file like this

```xml
<framework src="com.google.zxing:core:3.3.0" value="gradle" />
<framework src="com.google.zxing:javase:3.3.0" value="gradle" />
```

And importing the packages in the code like this

```java
import com.google.zxing.BarcodeFormat;
import com.google.zxing.WriterException;
import com.google.zxing.client.j2se.MatrixToImageWriter;
import com.google.zxing.common.BitMatrix;
import com.google.zxing.qrcode.QRCodeWriter;
```

And this is the part of the code that uses ZXing

```java
boolean printQRCode(CallbackContext callbackContext, String str) throws WriterException, IOException {
    try {
        QRCodeWriter qrCodeWriter = new QRCodeWriter();
        BitMatrix bitMatrix = qrCodeWriter.encode(str, BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE, 100, 100);
            
        ByteArrayOutputStream pngOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        MatrixToImageWriter.writeToStream(bitMatrix, "PNG", pngOutputStream);
        byte[] pngData = pngOutputStream.toByteArray(); 

        mmOutputStream.write(pngData);

        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "PRINT QRCODE SENT");
        callbackContext.success("PRINT QRCODE SENT");
        return true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        String errMsg = e.getMessage();
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, errMsg);
        e.printStackTrace();
        callbackContext.error(errMsg);
    }

    return false  
}
```

The thing is I'm receiving the following errors

> error: package com.google.zxing.client.j2se does not exist
>
> error: cannot find symbol (MatrixToImageWriter)

I found some solutions in SO and Google but none of them explain how to solve the issue in a Cordova project setup. I'm really not very experienced in Java and, if possible, I would prefer to just configure ZXing through the `plugin.xml` file. Any

Thanks!